# Double foreach loop failed by reading out xml attribut with simplexml PHP

Tags: php, xml, loops, foreach, simplexml

I´m a starter in reading out XML by PHP simplexml_load_file. My problem is to read out single Elements who have an ID as an attribut. Also I want to echo out all types in color black (searching by HEX-code: #000000 because it is´nt even the same id in variation).

**See my example below:**

file.xml

```
<products>
        <types>
           <name>Artikel</name>
           <description>blablabla</description>
           <variations>
             <variation id=2>
               <name>black</name>
               <colors>
                 <color index="1">#000000</color>
               </colors>
            </variation>
          <variations>
            <variation id=1>
              <name>white</name>
              <colors>
               <color index="2">#FFFFFF</color>
              </colors>
          </variation>
         </variations>
       </types>
       <types>
           <name>Artikel</name>
           <description>blablabla</description>
           <variations>
             <variation id=7>
               <name>black</name>
               <colors>
                 <color index="6">#000000</color>
               </colors>
            </variation>
          <variations>
            <variation id=90>
              <name>black</name>
              <colors>
               <color index="3">#000000</color>
              </colors>
          </variation>
         </variations>
       </types>
    </products>
```

Using PHP I can find out all of it with:

```
<?php

    $products = simplexml_load_file(xml.file);
        /*echo '<pre>';
        print_r ($products); //all products
        echo '</pre>';*/

        foreach ($products as $types)
        {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r ($types);
            echo '</pre>';
            foreach ($products->variation as $variation)
            {
                echo '<pre>';
                echo $variation;
                echo '</pre>';
            }
                        if (color == #00000)  /*I know this is wrong, it is just my base for solving*/
                        {
                                echo types;
                        }

        }
?>
```

Code PHP projekt:

```
  <?php

    $productTypes = simplexml_load_file('http://api.spreadshirt.net/api/v1/shops/611779/productTypes?fullData=true');
        /*echo '<pre>';
        print_r ($productTypes);
        echo '</pre>';*/

        foreach ($productTypes as $productType)
        {
            /*echo '<pre>';
            print_r ($productType);
            echo '</pre>';*/
            foreach ($productType->appearances->appearance[0] as $appearances)
            {

                //echo $appearances. '</br>';
                foreach ($appearances->colors->color['#000000'] as $color)
                {

                    echo $color. '</br>';
                    if ($color == 'black');
                    {
                    echo $color;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
?>
```

Comment: Show your print_r ($products);

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but sorry it doesn´t work anymore. I don´t know why. :(

Comment: I´m also in progress to find the error!

Comment: can you give me the feed url or file. i will guide you

Comment: Ok, I took this example for learning this system before I solve a bigger projekt. It is to find out all productTypes which color black from following url: http://api.spreadshirt.net/api/v1/shops/611779/productTypes?fullData=true . I come till $appearances, but cannot find out the colors. I guess it´s a problem with the index-attribut.

Comment: Nathan, you can see it up - the last one.

Comment: ok wait i will help u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This its working fine

```
$products = simplexml_load_file('http://api.spreadshirt.net/api/v1/shops/611779/productTypes?fullData=true');    

        $allproducts = $products->productType;
        foreach ($allproducts as $types)
        {           
           $app = $types->appearances;
           $appearance = $app->appearance;
           $color = $appearance->colors;
           $colors = $color->color;
            foreach ($colors as $colornew)
            {
                if ($colornew == '#FFFFFF');
                    {
                    echo 'white<br>';
                    }
                if($colornew=='000000') //this is a black
                    {
                        echo $name =  $types->name;
                    echo $shortDescription = $types->shortDescription;
                     $price = $types->price;
                    //echo  $vatExcluded = $price['vatExcluded'];
                                            echo  $vatExcluded = $price->vatExcluded."<br>";
                    }               

            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, that´s great. Thank´s a lot! ;)I changed the color into black and tried to echo out §allproducts which color black, but it doesn´t work. I thought I could put it into echo $allproducts. Do you have any idea?

Comment: your feed contains only color attributes. What you want. why you want black. explain clearly

Comment: Ok, in sum I want to print out all products that have color black! That´s it. Now I know which path I take to come to color black, but I can´t find the output from all productTypes availible in black:

Comment: productType --> name --> description --> price --> and so on, but only these which in black availible. Also all properties from a black productType...

Comment: I checked, it works! Yeah. Thank you very much. I just thought to short it up in 1 tag. :)

Comment: but the 'vatexcluded' does´n work output:"Warning: Illegal string offset 'vatExcluded' in \pTypes_black.php on line 19" I´m searching and trying....to be continued.

Comment: change this echo  $vatExcluded = $price->vatExcluded."<br>";